# how to find the clock cycles using microblaze

Tags: microblaze

I'm a beginner with the Microblaze.

I just want to know how much clock cycles will use some instructions.

Variable s0 would be mapped to a register (in register file) x5, and s1 to x6;
the assembly code would be

- load s0 from memory to register file (how many clock cycle it takes?)
- load s1 from memory to register file (how many clock cycle it takes?)
- do the logical AND (how many clock cycle it takes?)
- address calculation and store instruction (how many clock cycle it takes?)

Answer (score 0):

> load s0 from memory to register file (how many clock cycle it takes?)

> load s1 from memory to register file (how many clock cycle it takes?)

> address calculation and store instruction (how many clock cycle it takes?)

The `lw`, `sw`, and other similar assembly instructions have a latency that is dependent on how che Microblaze has been syntesized; they take

- 1 clock cycle when Microblaze is synthesized with the C_AREA_OPTIMIZED parameter to 0
- 2 clock cycles when C_AREA_OPTIMIZED=1

This assumes the use of local BRAM memory resources; if you are using a memory over another bus interface, you should add the memory bus latency.

> do the logical AND (how many clock cycle it takes?)

The `and`, `andi`, `andn`, `andni` (and many other assembly instructions) take 1 clock cycle on the Microblaze.

In general, you know your assembler code: you should look at the Microblaze PDF documentation (a version for ISE 14.7 can be found [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/mb_ref_guide.pdf))